# Multiple-entry Schengen visa

Tags: visas

I am travelling from July 1 to July 9 for business and then to Spain, August 24 to September 11 as a tourist. Can I apply for a multiple-entry Schengen visa for both trips? Which would be the member state and can I get visa through the Spanish embassy?

Comment: For clarity, where are you going for your first trip and what’s your nationality?

Answer (score 4):

Apply to the country that is the main destination of your first trip.

If you write that you are planning another trip to Schengen, they *might* be nice and issue you a multiple entry visa, and then you have a visa for your second trip, they might also be less nice and only issue a single entry visa (depending on a lot of factors, your - as I write this, undisclosed - nationality being one, you often need a good travel history to get a multiple entry visa), in which case you'll also have to apply to Spain for a visa for the second trip.

Of course there's also the possibility that your application will be refused.

Comment: I am South African. Its worth a try. I may be lucky! Thank you!